# how to disable smart lookup from office 365?

Tags: office365

I found the new tool called smart lookup, which unfortunately send datas without my consent if I understood correctly.

I found no way to deactivate it.

Searching for it on the web with words such as deactivate, disable, returned no result.

Is there a way to prevent it from sending information without my consent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have authorized this app, it will be listed in your settings.  Logon here:  https://portal.office.com/account/#apps

You should then have a list of all the apps you have authorized to access your account.  On this page, you can then revoke access to it.

If that link give's you trouble you get there by:

1. Logging into Office 365
2. Click the settings icon (little gear top right corner)
3. Select Office 365 settings
4. Then select App Permissions from the left

Comment: helps me for even more than the original question!! thx a lot!